# How to compare element of two arraylist and how to save common elements among them in anothet arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two arraylists.I want to compare the elements of each arraylist and want to save the common elements among those arraylists in another arraylist?

Comment: Please tag your question with a language.

Comment: What did you try?  Why did that not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code below:

```
public ArrayList<String> compareLists(ArrayList<String> list1 , ArrayList<String> list2){

    ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String str : list1) {
        if(list2.contains(str)){
            resultList.add(str);
        }
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new ArrayList<> (l1).retainAll(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

[retainAll() in arrayList](http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/arraylist/arraylist_retainall.php)

You can refer to this link, here they have used the retainAll method in ArrayList to get the common elements between the two lists.